# Is there a way to join 2 data tables on multiple columns through Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, join, multiple-columns

I have two data tables.

1st table:

[image]

2nd table:

[image]

I want the following result:

[image]

But I'm getting this result instead:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
table1.Columns.Add("D");

table1.AsEnumerable()
      .Join(table2.AsEnumerable(),
            dt1_Row => dt1_Row.ItemArray[0],                         
            dt2_Row => dt2_Row.ItemArray[0],
            (dt1_Row, dt2_Row) => new { dt1_Row, dt2_Row})
      .ToList()                         
      .ForEach(o => o.dt1_Row.SetField(3, o.dt2_Row.ItemArray[2]));
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. [ask]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. On error pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Thank you @philipxy , i pasted images because it was fast and it showed what i want to show precisely, and i looked out every possible solution on the world wide web, and i think i was clear i wanted to join 2 data tables, i dont know where you got confused, anyway, thanks for your time, i really do appreciate it!

Comment: I am not confused, I am telling you things to help you get answers & upvotes instead of downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer -

```
        DataRow dataRow = null;
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add("A");
        dt1.Columns.Add("B");
        dt1.Columns.Add("C");
        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Australia";
        dataRow["B"] = "P1";
        dataRow["C"] = "15";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Australia";
        dataRow["B"] = "P2";
        dataRow["C"] = "4";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Australia";
        dataRow["B"] = "P3";
        dataRow["C"] = "4";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Australia";
        dataRow["B"] = "P4";
        dataRow["C"] = "51";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Australia";
        dataRow["B"] = "P5";
        dataRow["C"] = "4";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Canada";
        dataRow["B"] = "P1";
        dataRow["C"] = "9";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        
        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Canada";
        dataRow["B"] = "P2";
        dataRow["C"] = "5";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Canada";
        dataRow["B"] = "P3";
        dataRow["C"] = "19";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Canada";
        dataRow["B"] = "P4";
        dataRow["C"] = "79";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dataRow = dt1.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Canada";
        dataRow["B"] = "P5";
        dataRow["C"] = "23";
        dt1.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dt1.AcceptChanges();

        dataRow = null;
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add("A");
        dt2.Columns.Add("B");
        dt2.Columns.Add("D");
        dataRow = dt2.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Australia";
        dataRow["B"] = "P1";
        dataRow["D"] = "2";
        dt2.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dataRow = dt2.NewRow();
        dataRow["A"] = "Canada";
        dataRow["B"] = "P1";
        dataRow["D"] = "3";
        dt2.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        dt2.AcceptChanges();


        var joinResult = (from p in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                          join t in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                          on new
                          {
                              A = p.Field<String>("A"),
                              B = p.Field<String>("B"),
                          } equals
                           new
                           {
                               A = t.Field<String>("A"),
                               B = t.Field<String>("B"),
                           }
                          into grp1
                          from tb3 in grp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new
                          {
                              A = p.Field<string>("A"),
                              B = p.Field<string>("B"),
                              C = p.Field<string>("C"),
                              D = tb3 == null ? "0" : tb3.Field<string>("D")

                          });
```

finally, you can enumerate A,B,C,D fields using foreach loop.

Comment: thank you for this, i tweaked this code a bit here and there, but these was precisely i wanted, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this suffice?

```
    var r = from t1 in table1
            from t2 in table2.Where(t=> t.A == t1.A && t.B == t1.B).Select(t=>t.D).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t2.D}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the below solution:

```
var list1 = (from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             A= t1.Field<string>("A"),
                             B = t1.Field<string>("B"),
                             C = t1.Field<int>("C").ToString(),
                             
                         });

            var list2 = (from b in table2.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             A = b.Field<string>("A"),
                             B = b.Field<string>("B"),
                             D = b.Field<int>("D").ToString(),
                             
                         });
            var result = (from x in list1.AsEnumerable()
                          join y in list2.AsEnumerable() on new { x.A, x.B } equals new { y.A, y.B } into xy
                           from y in xy.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new { x,xx = y == null ? "0" : y.D  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers, explain how it is an answer to the question & what the problems or misconceptions in the question were.

Comment: @philipxy i was able to join two datatables on multiple columns, as i explained in the question i was unable to reach the goal with code i posted in the question, in the end i had to change code(with the help of internet) and so thought of posting here, Please let me know if you have any specific part which you don't understand, i will gladly like to help!

Comment: Again, I am just tellijng you about using the site in a way to help yourself & others. The point of SO is to be a collection of good Q&A, and dumps of code are not good answers. [answer] [help]

Comment: Thank you! i hope there were good questions to answer!